# Intl.NumberFormat.prototype.formatToParts support for Safari older version from 13

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

i got an error on my application that `**formaTtoParts**` is not defined

```js
TypeError: Intl.NumberFormat(t,{minimumFractionDigits:2}).formatToParts is not a
function. (In 'Intl.NumberFormat(t,{minimumFractionDigits:2}).formatToParts(ri(e))',
 'Intl.NumberFormat(t,{minimumFractionDigits:2}).formatToParts' is undefined)
```

```
browser.name:
Mobile Safari UI/WKWebView

device:
iPhone

interface_type:
exception

os:
iOS 12.5.5
```

Is it possible to find a polyfill please for alternate solution that supports previous version of Safar from 13 ???

Comment: Check out the [documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat). There are details on supported browsers/environments by function including formatToParts, and a link to a polyfill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/components#formattednumberparts

```
React Intl has a set of React components that provide a declarative way to
 setup an i18n context and format dates, numbers, and strings for display in 
a web UI. The components render React elements by building on React Intl's imperative API.
```

this might help us on the device when `Intl.NumberFormat.prototype.formatToParts`is not supported

Here is the file to check more details on the implementation:
[FormatNumericToParts.ts](https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/blob/bf915ea22650ca91444dc228f4bbe7957da2924d/packages/ecma402-abstract/NumberFormat/FormatNumericToParts.ts)

Moreover, can use the `@formatjs` as a polyfill too

```
import '@formatjs/intl-numberformat/polyfill'
import '@formatjs/intl-numberformat/locale-data/en' // locale-data for en
```